# ZipArchive contains files but folder is empty after extraction

Tags: c#

The following code generates and downloads a zip file with a file called foo.txt.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadZip()
{
    using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("foo.txt");

            using var entryStream = zipEntry.Open();

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write("bar");
            }
        }

        zipStream.Position = 0;

        return File(zipStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "file.zip");
    }
}
```

When opening the zip file in windows I can see foo.txt, however after extraction the folder is empty. Any ideas why?

Comment: If you have problems extracting from the zip shouldn't you show that code? Or is your story missing some details?

Comment: @Ralf I download the file and do extraction in windows with the built in zip program.

Comment: I just tried the code with .net7.0.304, I did little changes from the default mvc template, and it worked (saw "bar" from the extracted file), the downloaded file is exactly 123 bytes.

Comment: @shingo hmm thx for the info. Can you try with net6?

Comment: net6.0.202 also works.

Comment: @shingo okay strange, please post your solution and I will investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the steps I tried to reproduce:

1. Create the project.

   ```sh
   mkdir asptest
   cd asptest
   dotnet new mvc
   ```
2. Update **Controllers\HomeController.cs**, add your method to the `HomeController` class, and these 2 usings.

   ```
   using System.IO;
   using System.IO.Compression;
   ```
3. Update **Views\Home\Index.cshtml**, append the following lines.

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadZip", "Home"))
   {
       <input type="submit" value="Download" />
   }
   ```
4. Run the app.

   ```sh
   dotnet watch
   ```
5. Click the Download button to download the file.

---

The response:

```text
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/zip
date: Mon, 09 Oct 2023 14:56:04 GMT
server: Kestrel
content-length: 123
content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip; filename*=UTF-8''file.zip
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

The zip file:

```text
UEsDBBQAAAAIAAK3SVeqjP92CwAAAAMAAAAHAAAAZ
m9vLnR4dEpKLAIAAAD//wMAUEsBAhQAFAAAAAgAAr
dJV6qM/3YLAAAAAwAAAAcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAGZvby50eHRQSwUGAAAAAAEAAQA1AAAAMAAAAAAA
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to the OPs question. Also, did you manage to reproduce the same issue or not? The zip file as you posted it doesn't really tell us...

Comment: Please take a look at the comments in the question, I managed to reproduce the question but I got a zip file that can be extracted. The zip file is base64 encoded,  others who are trying can compare whether the file content is consistent.